# Is it "Hashir" or "Al-Hashir"?

Tags: fiqh, arabic, naming

Our family is in the process of naming a new born and they would like to go for the name "Hashir," which is one of the names of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH). When I heard the name, I said that it had to be "Al-Hashir" not "Hashir" but it seems to be difficult to maintain the "Al" in the name so I am not sure if naming the baby simply as "Hashir" is correct both Islamically and grammatically?

I did some googling and there seems to be some websites that list the word "Hashir" but the arabic version is almost always "Al-Hashir."

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

All Praise to Allah Swt and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon his His family and companions.

Narrated Jubair bin Mut`im:

Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "I have five names: I am Muhammad and Ahmad; I am Al-Mahi through whom Allah will eliminate infidelity; I am **Al-Hashir** who will be the first to be resurrected, the people being resurrected there after; and I am also Al-`Aqib (i.e. There will be no prophet after me).([Bukhari](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/61/41))

Arabic "Al" is a definite article which means "The" in English so here in this Hadith it is used as "The" like Al-Madinatul Munawwarah a specific name but for calling a name just Hashir is fine.

Allah swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Is it a good name? A friend who's from the Middle East said it was not a popular name in the Arab world and most wouldn't know it's meaning if asked. Your thoughts? Should we go with it?

Comment: Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him  said, "Keep the names (of your children) on my name and not on my Kunniyat (Title).Ibn Asakir and Hussain Ibn Ahmad has stated that Muhammad peace be upon him said, "If a son is born to you and out of love and respect for me and to obtain the blessings of my name, you keep the child's name 'Muhammad', then the father and child will both enter Jannah.".So it is definitely a nice name as it is one of  name of Muhammad peace be upon him & he said"...I am Hashir (the gatherer) at whose feet mankind will be gathered...." .Muhammad Hashir is good name .